# Jest mock test using Sanity npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I have some code in my `sanity.ts` file:

```js
import sanityClient from '@sanity/client';

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
const blocksToHtml = require('@sanity/block-content-to-html');

const client = sanityClient({
  projectId: '',
  dataset: '',
  apiVersion: '2021-05-11',
  token: String(process.env.SANITY_API_KEY),
  useCdn: false,
});

export async function getData(): Promise<void> {
  const query = '';
  const sanityResponse = await client.fetch(query);

  return;
}
```

I'm trying to mock this when I'm testing it, but I'm having issues setting up the mock. I keep getting `TypeError: client_1.default is not a function`. This is what I have in my Jest test file:

```
jest.mock('@sanity/client', () => {
  const mClient = {
    fetch: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { client: jest.fn(() => mClient) };
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

made a `__mocks__` folder with the following code and got a different error:

```
class sanityClient {}
const client = jest.fn(() => new sanityClient());

const fetchMock = jest.fn();

client.prototype = {
  fetch: fetchMock,
};

module.exports = sanityClient;
module.exports.client = client;
module.exports.fetch = fetchMock;
```

`TypeError: client.fetch is not a function`

Any help?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce locally. Try adding `console.log(sanityClient)` to `sanity.ts` to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work: For anyone you need to mock the fetch as a function of sanity:

```
jest.mock('@sanity/client', () => {
  return function sanity() {
    return {
      fetch: () => ({
        methodOne: [{}],
        methodTwo: [{}],
      }),
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: This really helped me, thanks. Can you share how you were able to figure this answer out?

Comment: It's pretty similar to mocking other packages, so this is standard in their docs. It just took a while to mock sanity specifically